# Angular 4 --aot issue

Tags: angular

I have an angular 4 application that I can't seem to build in -aot format.
When I use

```
ng build --aot=false
```

it builds (and runs) fine but if I use

```
ng build --aot
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR in Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DataService in C:/Users/Shane/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/GG_Website/GG_Website/src/app/shared/services/data.service.ts: (?, [object Object]).
at Error (native)
at syntaxError (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15816:35)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15684:26)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15670:21)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15961:40)
at C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15890:49
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15850:19)
at C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15425:63
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15416:49)
at addNgModule (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24268:58)
at C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24279:14
at Array.forEach (native)
at _createNgModules (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24278:26)
at analyzeNgModules (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24153:14)
at analyzeAndValidateNgModules (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24163:35)
at AotCompiler.analyzeModulesAsync (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23797:46)
at CodeGenerator.codegen (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:32:14)
at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:73:30)
at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then (C:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\GG_Website\GG_Website\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:391:44)
```

Here's part of the DataService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { StatusCodes } from './../status-codes';
import { AppError } from "app/common/errors/app-error";
import { NotFoundError } from "app/common/errors/not-found-error";
import { ErrorObservable } from "rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable";
import { BadRequestError } from 'app/common/errors/bad-request-error';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

 constructor(
    private _url: string,
    private _http: Http) {
 }
}
```

It all works as expected when I don't use ahead of time compilation.
What am I missing?

Also how important is ahead of time compiling?

Comment: Ahead of time compiling is important because it improves performance a lot and reduces the amount of output when loading the website. It’s basically optimised to production release. Now regarding your error it can be a multitude of things like a 3rd party lib not being compiled properly or many other things.

Comment: Try using `ng serve --aot` and then debug through the chrome browser. You may be able to find the missing dependency.

Comment: what are the parameters for DataService constructor?

Comment: Without seeing your data service code, we cannot really help you.

Comment: @m.alek I just added the dataservice class